# Disappearing nodeValue

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to write a Javascript that sorts some paragraphs. Here's a small snippit of the HTML that I am sorting:

```
<p>Brown, John, 2010, <a href="#">Link</a></p>

<p>Bush, C.A., 2010, <a href="#">Link</a>: More info.</p>

<p><br></p>
<h3><a name="c">C</a></h3>

<p>Caine, J.S., and Minor, S.A., 2010, <a href="#">Link</a>: More</p>
```

This Javascript is looking for the entries that contain "2010" (which are 3 out of the 4 paragraphs):

```
var paras = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
alert( paras.length );  // 4, which is what I expect!

for( i=0; i < paras.length ; i++ ) {
    var node0_text = paras[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

    if ( node0_text.indexOf('2010') ) {
        alert( node0_text ); // not returning everything that I expect it to.
    };
}
```

When I run this the first 2 entries ("Brown" and "Bush") pop up in the alert box just as I expect they would. Then the script seems to die. It does not display the third ("Caine") entry. What went wrong here? Thanks for any input.

A link to it: http://jsfiddle.net/Jrmy/6MP2W/5/

Comment: When your javascript "dies" you will generally find a useful error message on your console.

Comment: Yup, James. That was a dumb miss on my part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Caine" entry is in the **fourth** paragraph. The script fails because the third paragraph has no text.

This is  the third paragraph:

```
<p><br></p>
```

The text is `null` so the `if` statement gets an exception for trying to access `.indexOf()`.

(*edit* — a good comment points out that it's the `<br>` tag being checked for a value, but that's null too.)

Comment: To be precise, it's because the `nodeValue` of `<br>` is `null`, isn't it?

Comment: @bfavaretto yes I guess so, as that's the first (and only) child.

Comment: Thanks, Pointy! I saw that it was returning null, but assumed the loop would continue. I guess I need a better way to match my search.